# How to switch back to keyboard/terminal input after using freopen() in C++?

Tags: c++, file-io, user-input, stdio

I need to take input from a file and store some values. Then I want to receive some queries from the user. So if I use `freopen()` to read from a file, then how can I switch back to keyboard or terminal input?

I used `freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);`

Comment: Why do you need `freopen` to read from a file? Why not just `fopen` it and read from the `FILE*` handle returned therefrom?

Comment: Using `freopen` to make `std::cin` a file does seem to be a fashion on here lately, don't do it, just use `std::ifstream`, it's so much simpler